# Not getting graph property by using syncfusion in my project

Tags: syncfusion

I want to use area and line graph together from syncfusion in my project for which I have tried out the code in stackblitz and is working properly, but when I'm trying out the same code in my editor (Visual Studio Code) then I'm not getting the required output (indexes are coming but the graph is not visible image attached below). I have also installed all the necessary packages and followed the steps that were mentioned in syncfusion's official website (`https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/demos/#/material/chart/area`)

Please guide me whether I should purchase the license or is there any other way or any other steps to get the graph.

Stackblitz working graph
[image]

my project graph
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This issue may occur, if you didn’t inject the required modules to the application, So inject the AreaSeriesModule and LineSeriesModule or the all the chart modules into your application and check it.